# Can closing a covered call and opening a new covered call trigger a wash sale?

Tags: united-states, taxes, option-strategies, wash-sale, covered-call

In Jan 2019, I bought 200 QQQ (ETF) at about $160 and also wrote two covered calls for June 2019 at 170 (higher than the last day price) netting a small premium. Now QQQ is at about 185 so it will be assigned to me unless I cover it.

I am thinking to cover the existing call of $170 and simultaneously write another call at $180 for Dec 2019 so I get few cents of immediate profit without giving any further cash or stock.

My main question is, will these two transactions together will trigger a wash sale?

What happens to holding period (as new covered call will be at lower than the last day price)? I plan to hold the position so I pay long term capital gains.

I looked at [Can buying covered calls to close trigger a wash sale](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/103662/) and [Are two options ever too similar for taxes?](https://money.stackexchange.com/questions/107195/) but they do not relate to the situation above.

Some other links to consider are:

- https://www.elitetrader.com/et/threads/wash-sale-rule-for-options.26435/
- https://greentradertax.com/tax-treatment-for-trading-options/
- https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reversion_(finance)

---

EDIT

I like the idea from @BobBaerker (from the comments):

> Here's an out of the box suggestion. Covered calls and short puts are synthetically equal. The Jun $170 CC is equal to a Jun $170 put. Buy the Jun $170 put to offset your position and sell the Dec $180 put to open (execute as diagonal spread). Run the numbers to see how close they are. Comes June, if CC is assigned, no wash sale. If not, long put locks in CC position (no loss). Post assignment, make sure to account for interest earned on QQQ proceeds as well as modest dividend lost. I don't know if this runs afoul of tax law and even if so, will they pick it up?

Comment: Who cares if it triggers a wash sale?  Do you know what the result of a wash sale is?

Comment: Options at different expiration dates are “substantially identical”. It might be helpful if you included quotes because the spread roll from June $170 to Dec $180 is a debit not a 'few cents of immediate profit without giving any further cash or stock."

Comment: @bob-baerker yes as of now the spread roll is debit, but if QQQ goes down , it can trigger the limit order.

Comment: per https://www.elitetrader.com/et/threads/wash-sale-rule-for-options.26435/ 
 The code and regulations offer no help. They do not address whether differences in dates or strike prices are sufficient to take the option out of the wash sale rule.

Comment: Why do you care?  If there is a loss and you have a purchase within 30 days the amount of the loss is added to the basis of the purchase delaying the realization of the loss.  In most situations it makes no real functional difference whether or not a loss is washed.

Comment: @quid the loss will be on https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ190628C00170000?p=QQQ190628C00170000  and not QQQ itself that I have sold for $2.+ a few cents) , giving me a total about $400 on two options, now it is trading at about $19, so if some how i am lucky to get out of it at $15 with limit multi-leg order, I will need to pay about $3000 and this $3000 I want to bring back by selling https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/QQQ191231C00180000?p=QQQ191231C00180000

Comment: None of that has anything to do with the result of a wash sale.  Wash sales are about declaring a loss on your taxes.  Whether or not you get to take a loss of $X now, or if you have to add $X to the basis of another purchase and take the $X loss on your taxes later.  Wash sales are about taxes not trading.

Comment: It stands to reason that if a call is "substantially equivalent" to the underlying, then a call at one strike price is "substantially equivalent" to a call at another strike price.  See if this provides any clarity for you: https://greentradertax.com/tax-treatment-for-trading-options/  .

Comment: If you intend to let assignment occur if ITM in December then all of this is just accounting paperwork (a wash sale on the June $170 is deferred but not lost)   What I would be more focused on is the profit potential from the date of the roll until December.  Are you realizing enough premium per day for the roll to make it worthwhile for the next 6 months or are you just  digging in because you don't want to give up the underlying?

Comment: @bob-baerker I intend to hold on the position as I believe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mean_reversion_(finance) so at some point in time may not be Dec 2019, but June 2020 it will come to normal

Comment: @quid , let us say that I am ready to assume it as wash-sale, then the loss on QQQ190628C00170000 will be added to the cost basis of QQQ or other option ( QQQ191231C00180000)that was ( assuming what I am trying to do happens) sold

Comment: Here's an out of the box suggestion.  Covered calls and short puts are synthetically equal.  The Jun $170 CC is equal to a Jun $170 put.  Buy the Jun $170 put to offset your position and sell the Dec $180 put to open (execute as diagonal spread).  Run the numbers to see how close they are.  Comes June, if CC is assigned, no wash sale.  If not, long put locks in CC position (no loss).  Post assignment, make sure to account for interest earned on QQQ proceeds as well as modest dividend lost.  I don't know if this runs afoul of tax law and even if so, will they pick it up?

Comment: @quid - There may be no real functional difference in your ability to eventually deduct a wash sale but in some instances, there can be serious tax compications in doing so.  For starters, one could have to unnecessarily additional taxes in the current year due to the deferred wash sale loss.  Of greater consequence, if the deferred loss was very large, the $3k annual cap gain deduction could come into play, limiting one's ability to write off the loss.  The only exception to this would be someone with Trader Tax Status who therefore has  MTM accounting.

Comment: @BobBaerker Wouldn't buying the put start over the holding period on the shares?   It would be considered a protective put.  Don't get me wrong, I like the idea in principal.

Comment: @vphilipnyc - Tax regs on options are confusing and unclear so I'm going to punt.  Perhaps the [Fairmark](https://fairmark.com/investment-taxation/capital-gain/wash/wash-sales-and-options/) web site info might clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

You asked:
   Can closing covered call and opening a new coverd call trigger wash sale?

I believe the answer is yes. For example, if the option you buy back has 300 days to expiration and the new option has the same expiration and its strike price is 1% higher.

In this specific case you site, the expiration dates are different and the strike price is significantly different. Therefore, the wash rule should not apply.

If you own a stock and you protect it with a long put position then the dividends from the stock are not qualified.

Comment: It can trigger a wash sale but the wash sale should not apply? Here's the opinion from [GreenTrader](https://greentradertax.com/tax-treatment-for-trading-options/), a very reliable tax source of tax issues for investors and traders.  **As we stress in our extensive content on wash sale loss deferral rules, Section 1091 rules for taxpayers require wash sale loss treatment on substantially identical positions across all accounts including IRAs. Substantially identical positions include Apple equity, Apply options and Apple options at different expiration dates on both puts and calls.**